# Navigation bar in html formatting issue

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Website source:http://www.salefee.com/

I have a navigation bar on my website. I have formatted it using css.While on first page,It appears normal. But when I navigate to other section ,I can observe a cut on either side of a navigation bar. I couldn't figure out the issue.
The code and screenshots are as given below:

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and Toggle -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#anch-top"><img src="images/logo.PNG" style="height:45px; width:60px;">Salefee</a>
          </div>
          <!-- End Brand and Toggle -->
          <!-- Menu -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="#anch-top" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Sans-Serif">Home</a>
              </li>


              <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="#anch-gallery" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Sans-Serif">Gallery</a>
              </li>

              <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="#anch-pricing" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Sans-Serif"><marquee direction=right behavior=alternate width=65><super>STORY</super></marquee></a>
              </li>




               <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="#anch-team" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Sans-Serif">Team</a>
              </li>

              <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="#anch-contact" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Sans-Serif">Contact</a>
              </li>

               <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="jobs" style="font-family: Sans-Serif">JOBS</a>

               <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="blog" target="_blank" style="font-family: Sans-Serif">BLOG</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- End Menu -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Screenshot 1:(normal)
[image: The navigation bar appears normal]

Screenshot 2:(problem)
[image: The navigation bar has a cut on right and extreme left side]

Please help me out with the code...Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put at your css file:

```
.navbar.affix{    height: 52px;}
```

and

```
div#navbar-collapse-1 {
min-width: 100%;
}
```

That way it is responsive too, and it fits perfectly all screen widths

Answer (score 0):

You have specified height at .navbar.affix class in css. You should make the property value of height, 51px. You will see that it will fix the issue.

```
.navbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 51px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have style for **.navbar.affix** where *height* set to **46px** on all pages except home page, I think you should remove *height* property and just add **bottom: auto;**